# Adding User Pictures without My Sites set up

Tags: user, picture, my

How can I manually add a users photo to their account, without setting up My Sites.

On a SharePoint Blog Site, the user wants us to set up the blogs so that the users image shows up next to their name on the post. Which I found out how to easily do by changing the list setting for Created by to Name(with picture and details). But we do not have My Sites set up and would like to avoid this. Is there anyway to manually add a users photo to their account so that it would show up next to their name?  We do have mapping set up from AD to SharePoint for the picture attribute from the thumbnailPhoto AD attribute.

Comment: if you have setup the AD mapping then it should show the user's photo as it stores in the profile. did you run the full sync and also pwoershell to create thumbnail attribute?

Comment: This will work without My Sites?

Comment: Yes it will, if it is not working then please let us know the error.